# Having SQL Query not group results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a sql query that joins a few tables by `user_id`, the problem is is that I would like to see all the data from these tables.

At the moment I am querying the user table and the payment table and joining them based on the `user_id`.

I seem to only getting one result per user_id, now I know this it what is meant to happen but how (if possible), would I be able to show all the data from the payment table (ie I want to see multiple user ids that show the various payments that user has made).

I am currently using a left join, I'm thinking this may be the issue but switching it still isn't showing the results I am looking for.

This i my current join:

```
from user u 
left join u_subscription us 
on u.user_id = us.user_id 
left join u_detail ud 
on u.user_id = ud.user_id
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Nad

Full sql query:

```
select u.user_id as 'prop:User id', u.user_username as 'prop:username', u.user_email as 'Identity',u.user_created as 'Timestamp', us.user_subscription_expires as 'prop:Expires on', us.user_subscription_payment_provider as 'prop:Payment provider', us.user_subscription_modified, ud.user_detail_signup_country_iso3 as 'prop:Country'

from user u
left outer join user_subscription us
on u.user_id = us.user_subscription_user_id
left outer join user_detail ud
on u.user_id = ud.user_detail_user_id
```

Comment: Can you show the full query you're using? It sounds like you might have `GROUP BY u.user_id`, but without the full query we can't say for sure.

Comment: Please show the full query.

Comment: That was quick! I tried left outer join, no luck with that. I'm not using group by anywhere.

Comment: As @newfurniturey told, can you show us your full query please ?

Comment: with the left outer join replacement

Comment: Which table stores the payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find no flaws in your query. It should be working as expected.

I'm suspecting there is no more than one row *per user* in the `subscription` and `detail` tables. That's why your `left join` produces exactly one row per user (if it was an inner join, it would produce *at most* one row per user).

Comment: This is it, sorry I didnt realise! the db has changed and overwrites the user info rather than adding another row. Thanks for this and all the other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using another method:

```
select
   'your selected columns'
from
   user u,
   u_subscription us,
   u_detail ud
where 
   u.user_id = us.user_id and
   u.user_id = ud.user_id
```

this works just like the join method but for me, this method makes the query cleaner and easier to understand.. hope it helped!

Comment: This is syntactically the equivalent of just switching the LEFT OUTER joins to INNER JOINs, so would not solve the issue.

Comment: In addition the method you have proposed, while not wrong, is over 20 years old and was replaced in ANSI 1992 by the explicit join syntax used in the question. I would not like to speak on behalf of too many people, but I would argue that you are in the minority in thinking this is cleaner and easier to understand. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) gives more reasons to switch than I could in a comment

Comment: Ah.. I see.. Thanks @GarethD! I've learned a lot! I usually argue that my method is the better one but now I know.. The article was very informative! Thanks for the correction..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifically looking for something of details / payments, use THAT table as the basis of the query, then join to the users table as the detail would only exist based on a user...  However, you can left-join to the subscription if that is conditional.  Something like

```
select
      u.*,
      ud.*,
      us.*
   from
      u_detail ud
         join user u
            on ud.user_id = u.user_id
         left join u_subscription us
            on ud.user_id = us.user_id
```

Since the userID would be the same from user detail to the user table, just use the same for joining to the subscription table.  I normally would not use "*" for fields, but pick what you want from it.